# SSR protected pages in app directory of next js using HOC

Tags: authentication, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have this simple HOC code

```
'use client'
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const withAuth = (WrappedComponent: any) => {
  return (props: any) => {
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
      const isLoggedIn = true;
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        router.push("/en/auth/login"); // Redirect the user to the login page
      }
    }, []);

    return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
  };
};

export default withAuth;
```

and I have a server side rendered page located in app folder in the last next.js version
the page code is

```
import EmployerLayout from '@/shared/layouts/employer-layout/employer-layout';
import {Locale} from 'i18n-config';
import {getDictionary} from 'git-dictionary';
import withAuth from '@/shared/providers/with-auth';

async function Dashboard({
    params: {lang},
}: {
    params: {lang: Locale};
}) {
    const dictionary = await getDictionary(lang);
    return (
        <EmployerLayout dictionary={dictionary}>
            <p>This text is rendered on the server: {dictionary.jobbit}</p>
        </EmployerLayout>
    );
}
export default withAuth(Dashboard)
```

but here it till me that the issue I was passed the ssr page to client renderer function component as props and it not work in this case because the client component accept server component just as children

how could I fix this issue or what the solution for my needs if there another one?

I tried HOC behavior as client rendering and pass the ssr page to it